Request: visual feature reference for parts on bricks.stackexchange.com
It would be helpful to have some sort of visual feature reference on the site here to hint at what the community has accepted as standard terms to describe various features of LEGO pieces.  I grew up using the term "bumps", but a diagram like the following (from leonardoslegos.com Lego Vocabulary 101) would be a very helpful hint for Newbies (to the community) like me posting questions.
I'm not familiar with what controls are available for modifying the interface on SE sites, but I was thinking an image or link on the Ask Question page would be infinitely educational.  I'm not sure what tag wiki page would be equivalently appropriate.
Thoughts?


Typically we suggest people post lists of technical terms in a meta post and link to it when needed. I think you should assume most users understand and use the basic terminology of the field. Having the reference for newbies is handy, but it's probably overkill to put it on the Ask Question page. This question is a good start. Maybe you can expand it to other commonly used terms?
